# In what format should the input into a sequence to sequence learning model using RNNs be in?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm attempting to implement the neural conversational model described in [Vinyals et al 2015](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/papers/ancm.pdf). The question I have is in what format should the inputted sequence be in? I'm thinking of using word2vec or GloVe vector representations of the words in the sentence that I'm inputting into the encoder, but it seems computationally expensive to derive the vectors for all the words in my training data using word2vec or GloVe.

It is also to my understanding that the model can potentially output vectors that don't quite exist in the vector space of the embeddings created from the training vocabulary, and that I would have to use a KNN algorithm to find the nearest existing vector to the one outputted by the model, and this also seems very computationally expensive to do repeatedly while training the model.

Comment: Your question seems a bit unfocused. But generally you can either use 1-hot vectors or an embedding layer as the first layer which learns the representations automatically (it's not really significantly more expensive, in fact you have less parameters than with 1-hot). There's also no need for kNN.

Comment: @runDOSrun Would you suggest that I pass the one-hot encoded vectors for each word into the encoder or train a Word2Vec model on the training vocabulary and pass in the corresponding w2v embedding for each word?

Comment: I'd suggest trying both, depending on your data, you'll probably see the best choice rather quickly. 1-hot quickly uses up your RAM while embeddings are more space-efficient. w2v gives you an embedding matrix which you load into your first weight matrix (embedding layer).

Comment: glove is actually quite fast.